# How would I combine these string values into one row?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation, apply

Say you have columns A, B, and C.

Row 1 is Blue | Red | Silver

Row 2 is Blue | Red | Gold

How would I combine these so it becomes two rows,

Blue|Red|Silver,Gold

So that the third column concatenates any categories that fall into row 2 as value,value

I've tried experimenting with apply, merge, concatenate, but to no avail. Assuming its a larger dataset than the example, I have to iterate through all the rows to apply the new formatting.

Comment: df.groupby(['c1','c2'])['c3'].agg(','.join)

Comment: Ugh.. Thanks WeNYoBen.. I kept seeing examples of groupby using mean, sum, I assumed it only worked with number values. Frickin' agg. Thanks man.

Comment: @WeNYoBen: that's cool

Comment: As a slight variant of @WeNYoBen's proposal, you can also use `df.groupby('c1')['c3'].agg(lambda ser: ser.str.cat(sep=','))`. But if there is a difference at all, then probably only if you have groups with very many entries.